# Accessing static array in namespace returning zero

Tags: c++, arrays, namespaces, static-methods

As you can see from the code below, I have a namespace with a couple static functions and a static 2D float array. My problem is with the return value of the second function: it's returning 0 when it should be returning 1.16 (the value 'coefficients').

I've stepped through and 'coefficients' always has the correct values, even in autos the value for coefficients[one*2][two] is correct. There are no errors with reading from the file. The materials I am passing in are both 6 (rubber), so it's not going outside the bounds of the array.

Please help! It has me and a buddy both stumped. (PS: sorry for the weird indentation)

```
enum Material
{
    ICE = 0, 
    GLASS = 1, 
    CONCRETE = 2, 
    WOOD = 3,
    METAL = 4,
    SMOOTH_METAL = 5, 
    RUBBER = 6
};


 namespace Materials
    {
    static float coefficients[14][7];

    static void ReadFrictionCoefficientsFromFile()
    {
        std::ifstream file("FrictionCoefficients.csv");



if (!file.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR: cannot open file FrictionCoefficients.csv" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    std::string line;
    float val;
    int row = 0;
    while (std::getline(file, line))
    {
        std::stringstream ss(line);
        int col = 0;
        while (ss >> val)
        {
            coefficients[col][row] = val;
            if (ss.peek() == ',') ss.ignore();
            col++;
        }
        row++;
    }
    file.close();
    }


    static float GetCombinedStaticFriction(const Material m1, const Material m2)
    {
        int one = (int)m1, two = (int)m2;
        if (one > two)
        {
            one = (int)m2;
            two = (int)m1;
        }
        return coefficients[one * 2][two]; // -- ISSUE -- //
    }
}
```

Edit: Added lines that call the relevant functions

```
Materials::ReadFrictionCoefficientsFromFile();
friction_static = Materials::GetCombinedStaticFriction(body1->rigidbody.material, body2->rigidbody.material);
```

Comment: Can you show the code that calls `ReadFrictionCoefficientsFromFile` and then only once done   `GetCombinedStaticFriction`

Comment: @Jean-MarcVolle added

Comment: Have you used a debugger so far? Or some system outputs, like every time a value is read, printing the value, the current row and the current column? And afterwards, printing the whole array? (Both can be done without prints using a debugger, which is the preferable way.)

Comment: Other than that, I'd strongly recommend making this a class. Global variables are error prone, and right now, you even access it somewhat like a class.

Comment: I have, which makes it weirder because all the values, apart from the return value, are correct! I've also tried making a float var just above return and setting it to coefficients[12][6] and it doesn't set that var despite in the autos list showing the value at that index to be 1.16.

Comment: Then I'd assume that the access function has a bug. Try the following: 1. Print out `one*2` and `two` and their value, 2. print out the value at hard coded coefficients (`cout << coefficients[12][6] << endl;`) afterwards. Might be that `one*2` and `two` are not 12 and 6 for some reason. Btw, I saw your reply because I was still here, but I wouldn't have otherwise - use @some_username for replies (except if you reply to a questioneer).

Comment: @Aziuth Gave it a go, coefficients[12][6] wrongly printed 0, so there's some problem with accessing it... looks like I'm gonna have to make this a class! Thanks for the tip btw

Comment: In your other comment, you wrote that the values are correct - does that mean that they are correct when you print them/look at them in the reading function but not when you do that in the access function? In any case, another recommedation: use a container class, like `std::array`, `std::vector` or `std::map` for the data.